# Delete Row using HandlerBars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to Implement delete row functionality in a html page using handler bars template. i have already created the adding of rows using Handlerbars template. Now i want to delete them individually whenever a delete button is clicked.

Comment: show us what have you done so far

Answer (score 1):

Since you have't provided any of your HTML or templating code, I am going to guess that following html is being generated

```
<div class="grid-rows">
    <div class="row">
        <span>something</span>
        <span><a href="#" class="deleteBtn">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>something</span>
        <span><a href="#" class="deleteBtn">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span>something</span>
        <span><a href="#" class="deleteBtn">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is nothing to do with handlebars while removing rows generated using handlebars. You can use the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
```